# Storing data in the nodes of a Binary Tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm creating some basic AI for Tic-Tac-Toe in C++. It involves creating a Binary Tree that consists of a 'board' class. Each node randomly places a X or O and then creates two more children until someone has won or the game has been drawn. To keep track of the value of each node, I use an integer: -1 for O winning, 0 for draw, 1 for X winning and 2 for game still in progress. [Here is an example of what a game could look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RBYh.png)

After my tree has been populated, I will need to look through the left and right side of the root node and sum up all the leafs. The side with the higher sum will be the more desirable option of the initial two children.

I have some very rough code for the expansion of the tree that appears to work, however, when I attempt to sum up my tree after its expansion, I seem to have lost the value that each node contains. Here is my .cpp for the node

BTNode.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "BTNode.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

BTNode::BTNode(board gameboard, string setplayer)
    {
        value = 2; //assume the game is continuing
        cout << "Beginning a new node\n";
        nodeboard = gameboard;
        player = setplayer;
        expand();
    }

void BTNode::expand()
{
        //place a piece 
        cout << "Expanding";
        placerandom(player);
        //check to see if a leaf
        value = nodeboard.checkwinner(); //returns -1 for O win, 0 for draw, 1 for X win and 2 for game still in progress
        cout << "Value of this node: " << value << "\n";
        if (value == 2)
        {
            if (player == "X")
            {
                BTNode right(nodeboard, "O");
                BTNode left(nodeboard, "O");
            }
            else
            {
                BTNode left(nodeboard, "X");
                BTNode right(nodeboard, "X");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "A game had ended";
        }
}   

int BTNode::getvalue(int side)
        {
        //in case this node is the root, i will only want to check 1 side of the tree
        //-1 is left side, 0 is both, 1 is right
        int toreturn=0;
        if (value ==2)
            {
            if (side == -1)
                {
                toreturn = left ->getvalue(0);
                }
            if (side == 0)
                {
                toreturn = right->getvalue(0) + left->getvalue(0);
                }
            if (side == 1)
                {
                toreturn = right->getvalue(0);
                }
            }
            else
            {
            cout << "\nThis is a leaf, returning: " << value;
            toreturn = value;
            }
        return toreturn;
        }

void BTNode::placerandom(string player)
    {
    srand(time(NULL)); //make a new seed based off time
    int randx = rand()%3;
    int randy = rand()%3;
    while (not nodeboard.place(randx,randy,player))
        {
        randx = rand()%3;
        randy = rand()%3;
        }
    nodeboard.printboard();
    }
```

BTNode.h

```c++
#include <string>
#include "board.h"
using namespace std;
class BTNode
{
    public:
        BTNode(board gameboard, string setplayer);
        void placerandom(string player);
        int getvalue(int side);
        void expand();
    private:
        board nodeboard;
        string player;
        BTNode *left;
        BTNode *right;
        int value;
};
```

In theory, I should just be able to call "root -> getvalue(-1)" from the tree, which would return a summation of all the nodes beginning from the left side of the tree. However, attempting to get 'value' from any nodes after the expansion functions returns "-1131609994".

Have I created my tree wrong? It seemed quite promising until I attempted to sum it.

Comment: `BTNode(board gameboard, string set player);` Um. you know `gameboard` is passed by *value* here, right? I.e. the board in this constructor is a *copy* of the one passed in (and is then copied to the `nodeboard` member). The caller-side board remains unchanged. And things like `BTNode right(nodeboard, "O");` certainly aren't doing you any favors. Those lines do nothing but declare unused variables (passing a copy of `nodeboard` in the process).

Comment: I intended for the board to remain each time. Each node should have a copy of the board from its parent node, and then add its X or O to that copy. Like this http://i.imgur.com/IegZ7Gu.png.

As for "BTNode right(nodeboard, "O");" I would be lying if I had any idea what I was doing there, but It was the only way I could get it to work. I declared the left and right nodes in the header file, but wanted to initiate them in the expand event of the parent node. Couldn't find another way to do it :/

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, I was using "BTNode right(nodeboard, "O");" instead of "right = new BTNode(nodeboard, "O");"